# Инициализация членов структуры внутри другой структуры

Tags: c++, структуры, инициализация

Будут ли инициализированы члены структура `st1 st`(int a, int b) `нулем` внутри структуры `st2 st` ?

Например:

```
typedef struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    }st1;

    typedef struct {
        st1 st;
        int a;
        int b;
    }st2;
    
    st2 st = {};
```

Comment: А почему это не работает? согласно ассемблерному коду - все зануляется.

Comment: Да, тут будет проведена [агрегатная инициализация](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: а вот использование typedef конструкции немного напрягает (оно работает, но выглядит совсем не по плюсовому)

Comment: Вроде занулится, но всеравно лучше =0 у переменных писать.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков когда переменных мало, то, возможно, и лучше, а когда их с десяток, да еще и вложенные структуры...

Comment: @ЕгорФилатов то серавно лучше поставить =0 https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es20-always-initialize-an-object